# raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet..how to load the apps?

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g89q0.jpg)i was trying to run the following command::

```
python populate_book.py
```

and stuck with this error::

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

The Whole Traceback is as follow::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_book.py", line 6, in <module>
    from opac.models import Book, BookCopy
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/opac/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from transactions.models import EndUser
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/transactions/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class EndUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/prashant/Desktop/po/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

settings.py::

```
    # Django settings for cope project.
import os
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

ADMINS = (
    ('pulkit', 'data.pulkit@gmail.com'),
    ('shashank', 'shashankgrovy@gmail.com'),
    ('sourabh', 'sourabh.coder@gmail.com'),
    ('utsav', 'kumaruts@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'cope.db',
        # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '3306',
        # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"

MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'cope'), 'static'),
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'li=xy2zchjmi=)$+t$*yi5soc77yankx#=au+5&fy17_j3-#e%'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    # 'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'cope.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'cope.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'cope'), 'templates'),
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

LOCAL_APPS = (
    'opac',
    'transactions',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'bootstrap_admin',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + DJANGO_APPS

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

populate_book.py::

```
    import os
from random import randint
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cope.settings")

from opac.models import Book, BookCopy

def make_isbn():
    return randint(1000000000000, 9999999999999)

titles = ['Gray Hat Python', 'Introduction to Algorithms', 'Pro Python',
    'HTML5 and JavaScript Projects', 'NginX HTTP Server', 'Redis Cookbook',
    'Python Fundamentals', 'Land of Lisp', 'Beginning iOS Game Development',
    'Ruby on Rails for Dummies', 'Django, AJAX and jQuery']

authors = ['Seitz', 'Thomas H. Corman', 'Marty Alchin', 'Geanie Mayer', 'Clement',
    'Tiago Macedo', 'Kent Lee', 'Courad', 'Patrick', 'Barry Burd', 'Jonathan Hayward']

publishers = ['No Starch Press', 'Stanford Press', 'Apress', 'Apress', 'Packt OpenSource',
    'O\'Reilly', 'Springer', 'No Starch Press', 'WROK', 'For Dummies', 'Packt OpenSource']

imageurls = ['grayhat.png', 'introtoalgo.png', 'propython.png', 'htmljs.png', 'nginx.png',
    'redis.png', 'pythonfundamentals.png', 'lisp.png', 'ios.png', 'ror.png', 'djangoajax.png']

def main():
    for i in range(len(titles)):
        isbn = make_isbn()
        new_book = Book(title=titles[i], isbn=isbn, ddc=randint(100,999), authors = authors[i],
            publisher=publishers[i], cost=randint(300,700), imageurl=imageurls[i], pages=randint(300,700))
        new_book.save()
        print '\n%4d | ISBN: %s | Title: %s' % (i+1, isbn, titles[i])
        for j in range(randint(5,10)):
            book_number = randint(50000,900000)
            book_copy = BookCopy(book_number=book_number, book_category=new_book)
            book_copy.save()
            print '%10d | Book Number: %-6d | Category: %s' % (j+1, book_number, new_book.title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

manage.py::

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cope.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Do you have `apps.py` ?

Comment: No,I dont have apps.py.How to create it??

Comment: create an apps.py inside your appname folder and content like this : `""" app"""
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    """config"""
    name = 'AppName'

    def ready(self):
        # import signal handlers
        from . import notifications
`and try

Comment: created apps.py in opac/ and transactions/ but didnt help..
do i have to change the following in any form?::
    # import signal handlers from . import notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things that you should make sure,

- are all the apps you have in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting installed
  on your system?
- Have you perhaps forgotten to activate the virtualenv
  where everything was installed in the first place?
- If you have both of the things above on your system then maybe you
  forgot to install the apps from requirements in your venv? You can do this by `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Replace `requirements.txt` with whatever your requirements file's name is. Make sure you do this after activating the virtual environment.

Comment: I've checked     INSTALLED_APPS ,,
I activate virtualenv everytime,
Now how to install the apps from requirements in venv?
PS-please have a look at the screenshot attached in updated Question.

Comment: I do not see any screenshot but I have updated my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: see screenshot at link::

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g89q0.jpg

requiements didnt help,please do help.If you need to know anything else,please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Please once delete your virtual environment, and do the following in project root directory,
`virtualenv venv`
`source venv/bin/activate`
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Also, please check that requirements are up to date. Check for any typos with app names, etc.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.dangtrinh.com/2014/11/how-to-avoid-models-arent-loaded-yet.html

My advice would strongly be to perform this sort of operation within a Custom Management Command though https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/.